# Unable to do pip install mysql-python on virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql-python, macports

I use macports and I have successfully install mysql5 using macports, and my python also managed by macports. Currently I am trying to do pip install mysql-python on my virtualenv but I am getting an error which says, mysql_config not found:

```
    ~/code]$pip install mysql-python
    Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
      Running setup.py egg_info for package mysql-python
        sh: mysql_config: command not found
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
          File "~/myVirtualEnv/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
            metadata, options = get_config()
          File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
            libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
          File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
            raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
        EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        sh: mysql_config: command not found

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

      File "~/myVirtualEnv/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 18, in <module>

        metadata, options = get_config()

      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config

        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")

      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config

        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))

EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

I read many google examples but more I read helped me to confuse myself further.

Looks like macport have had a issue but it has been closed for while.. http://trac.macports.org/ticket/6982

Comment: Is there a ``mysql_config`` executable somewhere in path?

Comment: @Bogdan no I haven't added mysql_config on my bash_profile, honestly i am not sure where that exists.

Comment: I can make a guess that it should be installed along with the ``mysql5`` port. I do not know exactly how macports work; perhaps it is your responsibility to update your ``PATH`` after the installation (I use ``homebrew``, and it usually tells you such things right away). In any case, it does not seem like a Python problem.

Answer (score 3):

MacPort creates a symbolic link `mysql_config5` in `/opt/local/bin` to `/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_config`. Create another link called `mysql_config`.

```
cd /opt/local/bin
sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_config .
```

I seem to recall having to create a `my.cnf` too. By default Mac OSX uses all the defaults and doesn't create a `my.cnf`, create one `/etc/my.cnf`, it can be trivial.

Mine is just:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port = 3306
```

Comment: This is not the problem, its asking for the program called `mysql_config` not the configuration file for mysql.

Comment: Ohh, yes I had to add /usr/local/mysql/bin to my path. I had hit this problem a while ago. Updated my answer.

Comment: @achampion did you realized that I am using macports? `$which mysql5
/opt/local/bin/mysql5` thats my mysql path

Comment: macport mysql_config is found at /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin

Comment: @achampion so is it possible you could provide a concrete solution? because in your answer you are talking about /usr/local.. and i found mysql_config5 at the location you just profided. I am really confuse by your original answer which says add /usr/local....

Comment: @achampion `sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_config .` you have the  symlink to as `.` is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, `.` refers to the current directory and if you specific a directory it will use the same name as the target `mysql_config`. You can explicitly set it if you want `ln -s /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_config mysql_config` and it will result in the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_config is an executable that it is in the libmysqlclient package so you need to install. On Deb systems you could install this using

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

in RPM

```
RPM equivalent: sudo yum install mysql-devel
```

in mac maybe

```
Macports - port install mysql5 +server
```

Answer (score 0):

Add /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/ to your command search path and then rerun the "pip install" command should solve the problem.

```
export PATH=/opt/local/lib/mysql55/bin/:$PATH
pip install mysql-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and solved it:

1. Install `mysql`. If you have installed it, ignore this step.
2. `yum install mysql-devel`

   - If you encountered error like `Python.h: No such file or directory`,
     run `yum -y install python-devel`